# Helm Vault agent-inject-template annotations incorrect rendering

Tags: kubernetes-helm, vault

I'm using below agent inject annotations in my deployment file. But the rendered output is not what i'm expecting. TIA

```
    vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-secret-cos.json: "observability/data/dev/cosapikey"
    vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-template-cos.json: |
      {{`{{- with secret "observe/cosapikey" -}}
        {
          "credential": {
              "apikey": "{{ .Data.data.cosapikey }}"
            }
        }
      {{- end -}}`}}
```

**Output:** Notice the apikey doesn't have closed double quote in line number 4. this is throwing error in my application code

```
root@vault-demo-686fdcbdb7-4kvtj:/vault/secrets# cat cos.json
{
    "credential": {
        "apikey": "ddfdffsfjfjgjgdkdkfj
"}
  }
```

**Expected:**

```
root@vault-demo-686fdcbdb7-4kvtj:/vault/secrets# cat cos.json
{
    "credential": {
        "apikey": "ddfdffsfjfjgjgdkdkfj"
}
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The secret value probably has a newline character in the vault, so you should either change it or you can trim the value by putting - (minus sign) before/after the double braces:

```
"apikey": "{{- .Data.data.cosapikey -}}"
```